# C# Linq to select multiple columns by group and apply sum(aggregate function) on value field at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

How do I get the below result from C# Linq.

```
List<DataValues> dValues = getvalues().Tolist();
```

dValues Fields are:

```
[0]=    Year: 2014  Month:Jan   Location: "ABC" Value: 201
[1]=    Year: 2015  Month:Feb   Location: "ED"  Value: 560
[2]=    Year: 2014  Month:Jan   Location: "ABC" Value: 320
[3]=    Year: 2015  Month:Feb   Location: "EDF" Value: 240
```

Get Values from `dValues` group by `Year` and then `Month` and then sum the `Value` Column lastly get `Year`, `Month` `Location` and `Sum` column as Total.

I tried:

```
var sp = (from a in dValues 
          select new { a.Year, a.Month, a.LOCATION, a.Value }).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You want `sum` by group by `Year` and `Month` but also to select `Location`? Shouldn't it also be grouped by location?

Comment: **Gilad Green**, I tried to do this. **var sp = (from a in dValues select new {                        a.Year, a.Month, a.LOCATION, a.Value }).ToList();** but no luck how to apply sum or any aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want in order to perform any kind of aggregation of data is to use is `group by`. In your current attempt you just projected a new object. See this:

```
var result = (from item in getvalues()
                group item.Value by new { item.Year, item.Month, item.Location } into g
                select new {
                    Year = g.Key.Year,
                    Month = g.Key.Month,
                    Location = g.Key.Location,
                    Total = g.Sum()
                });
```

And in method syntax:

```
var result = getvalues().GroupBy(item => new { item.Year, item.Month, item.Location }, 
                                 selector => selector.Value)
                        .Select(grouping => new
                        {
                            Year = grouping.Key.Year,
                            Month = grouping.Key.Month,
                            Location = grouping.Key.Location,
                            Total = grouping.Sum()
                        });
```

Also - It is a shame to do `ToList` on `getvalues` - it executes the previous query and retrieves the data causing all further querying to take place in memory instead as sql in database.

Comment: Wow! Got a lot to learn, I will give a hit on the code then come back. thanks

Comment: **Gilad Green**, can we inject an additional row at the bottom of the all rows which will show the total for each column say that I have two or more value columns.

Comment: @Scavenger Where you present it you can add another row that its data is a separate query that just retrieves the sum of the `Value` with no grouping

Comment: **Gilad Green**, I did not get you, can you provide any sample please.

Comment: @Scavenger - unfortunately I shouldn't because it is a following question and it should be asked in a separate question

Comment: **Gilad Green**, Thanks for your response.